# Pass list of arguments to mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure there's a way to do this but I can't figure it out. I'd like to be able to pass a list of arguments to `mutate_at()` within a function without having to specify each argument

```r
library(tidyverse)

fake_data <-
  tibble(
    id = letters[1:6],
    ind_group_a = rep(0:1, times = 3),
    ind_group_b = rep(1:0, each = 3)
  )

#  id    ind_group_a ind_group_b
#   a              0           1
#   b              1           1
#   c              0           1
#   d              1           0
#   e              0           0
#   f              1           0
```

This function will then converts all 1's to "yes" and 0's to "no"

```r
recode_indicator <- function(x, if_1 = "yes", if_0 = "no") {
  ifelse(x == 1, if_1, if_0)
}
```

And I can use it fine like so:

```r
fake_data %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("ind_")),
    recode_indicator,
    if_1 = "Has",
    if_0 = "Missing"
  )

# id    ind_group_a ind_group_b
# chr> <chr>       <chr>      
#  a     Missing     Has        
#  b     Has         Has        
#  c     Missing     Has        
#  d     Has         Missing    
#  e     Missing     Missing    
#  f     Has         Missing
```

This is a simplified example but what I'd like to do is make it available in a function without having to write out all of the arguments. Ideally something short like `binary_values = list(...)`but I can't figure out how to pass these items as the additional arguments of `recode_indicator()`

```r
roll_up_indicators <- function(x,
                               #binary_values = list(if_1 = "yes", if_0 = "no"),
                               ...) {

  ind_cols <- grep("^ind_", names(x))

  df <-
    x %>%
    rename_at(ind_cols, str_remove, "^ind_") %>% 
    mutate_at(
      ind_cols,
      recode_indicator # ,
      # binary_values # <- here's the problem area
    ) %>%
    group_by_at(ind_cols) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup()

  knitr::kable(df, ...)
}


fake_data %>% roll_up_indicators()

#  |group_a |group_b |  n|
#  |:-------|:-------|--:|
#  |No      |No      |  1|
#  |No      |Yes     |  2|
#  |Yes     |No      |  2|
#  |Yes     |Yes     |  1|
```

**Update**

In terms of not rewriting all of the arguments, the `formals()` function can be used:

```r
roll_up_indicators <- function(x,
                               binary_values = formals(recode_indicator), # <--- formals
                               ...) {

  ind_cols <- grep("^ind_", names(x))

  df <-
    x %>%
    rename_at(ind_cols, str_remove, "^ind_") %>%
    mutate_at(
      ind_cols,
      partial(recode_indicator, !!!binary_values) # <--- the winning answer
    ) %>%
    group_by_at(ind_cols) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup()

  knitr::kable(df, ...)
}
```

Comment: Regarding the `recode_indicator` is it from a different package

Comment: I guess your function `recode_value` is `recode_indicator`.  Is that right?

Comment: I believe that is a typo considering it's used again below and the code works if you rename the function or replace the calls.

Comment: Ah, yes, a typo. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [`purrr::partial`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/partial.html) to specify that `if_1` and `if_0` arguments should come from `binary_values`:

```
roll_up_indicators <- function(x,
                               binary_values = list(if_1 = "yes", if_0 = "no"),
                               ...) {

  ind_cols <- grep("^ind_", names(x))

  df <-
    x %>%
    rename_at(ind_cols, str_remove, "^ind_") %>%
    mutate_at(
      ind_cols,
      partial(recode_indicator, !!!binary_values)    ## <--- partial() here
    ) %>%
    group_by_at(ind_cols) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup()

  knitr::kable(df, ...)
}

fake_data %>% roll_up_indicators()
#  |group_a |group_b |  n|
#  |:-------|:-------|--:|
#  |No      |No      |  1|
#  |No      |Yes     |  2|
#  |Yes     |No      |  2|
#  |Yes     |Yes     |  1|
```

Comment: Is it possible to import the args of `recode_indicator()` as the default values so that I don't need to type them all out or just pass `binary_values = recode_indicator()` and still pull it into `mutate_at()`?

Comment: @yake84: Use `binary_values = list()` in the `roll_up_indicators` signature. This will ensure that, by default, `partial` doesn't overwrite any default values of `recode_indicator()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to go with the pre-made functions, like recode, but I've also adapted your function if you wanted to add additional functionality. For that, I'm assuming that `binary_values` is appropriately named and will only ever include two values.

## Option 1: Use `recode`

This requires you to put the starting and ending values within a list. You'll need to quote strings, obviously and either quote or use `` around numbers.

```
binary_values = list("1" = "yes", "0" = "no") 
fake_data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ind_")),
            list(~recode(.,!!!binary_values)))
```

## Option 2: Specify location or name in list within function

```
recode_value <- function(x, 
                         binary_values = list(if_1 = "yes", if_0 = "no")
                         ## You'll need to decide whether you'll name them as expected or always put them in this order; it's up to you
                         ) {
  if_1 = binary_values$if_1 # or binary_values[[1]]
  if_0 = binary_values$if_0 # or binary_values[[1]]
  ifelse(x == 1, if_1, if_0)
}

binary_values = list(if_1 = "yes", if_0 = "no")
fake_data %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("ind_")),
    recode_value, ## fixed typo
    binary_values
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Your answer is helpful as it explains why I was having trouble. I gave it an up-vote but awarding the solution to the answer that uses the `purrr::partial()` approach.

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't heard of `partial` before and it's always to learn something new.